# Upload image file in server using ASIHTTPRequest from IPhone app

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest, image-upload, asiformdatarequest

I want to upload images in server using ASIHTTPRequest library in my IPhone app.

For image upload, i am using ASIFormDataRequest to upload into server.

I have tried the below codes in my app but it couldn't working and image didn't uploaded in server.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.anglerdemo.com/Appln/Aghaven_iphone/Uploadphoto.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.requestMethod = @"POST";
NSString *fileName = @"iphone.jpg";
[request addPostValue:fileName forKey:@"name"];

// Upload an image
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 90);
NSLog(@"imageData ==> %@", imageData);
[request setData:imageData withFileName:fileName andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"image"];
[request setDelegate:self]; 
[request startAsynchronous];
```

I have tried above codes in my app, request successfully executed and i got the alert message in "requestFinished" delegate method of ASIHTTPRequest. but image didn't uploaded in server.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
 {

[[[[UIAlertView alloc] 
   initWithTitle:@"Message" 
   message:@"Success!!!" 
   delegate:self 
   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
   otherButtonTitles:nil] 
  autorelease] 
 show];

NSLog(@"success ==> ");
}
```

I have tried php file script for upload is below.

```
<?php
   $uploaddir = 'upload_files/';
   $file = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
   $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
  {
   echo "Photo has been saved successfully!…;
  }
  else {
echo "Failed";
  }
?>
```

Please help in this regards.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first thing I would do is add

```
NSLog(@"%@", [request responseString]);
```

to requestFinished: just to be sure you see "Failed" being logged. This will prove the problem  is with the attempt to call move_upload_file, which I would guess is where things go wrong.

If that's the case, I would be pretty sure that the user your webserver runs as doesn't have write permissions to the upload_files directory.